# set a timeout for Airflow KubernetesPodOperator task

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, google-cloud-composer, airflow

I need a way to kill the running `KubernetesPodOperator` task after timeout, my `DAG` is scheduled to run `every 15 minutes`.

I tried to add `dagrun_timeout` and `max_active_runs` to the DAG arguments,

I expected this to stop the DAG  kill the running tasks and mark them as fail

but what actually happened is that the DAG is marked as failed and the tasks will continue running, and because the DAG is scheduled to run every 15 minutes, the DAG will get triggered and continue eventhough the task from the previous DAG RUN is still running

is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Can you try `startup_timeout_seconds` parameter when you create your `KubernetesPodOperator`? Sucha s described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator#pod_timeouts).

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I already use this but it's only for startup timeout

Comment: Can you share your logs ? So I can investigate further.

Comment: there is no error, everything works as supposed to , but I need to know if there's a way to terminate the triggered pod operator after a pre-selected timeout. when I used dagrun_timeout , after the timeout the dag failed as supposed to but the tasks continue to run, and when the next scheduled execution was triggered, I had a problem . when I used a timeout on the task as advised in the first answer, the task was marked as failed after the timeout but the pod continued in running on the kubernetes cluster and I faced the same problem

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/index.html), *specify how long a DagRun should be up before timing out / failing, so that new DagRuns can be created. The timeout is only enforced for scheduled DagRuns, and only once the # of active DagRuns == max_active_runs.* . Have your DAG runs reached the max active runs?

Comment: I used the max_active_runs, so here's the scenario:DAG scheduled to run every 10 minutes, only 1 operator(KubernetesPodOperator), the code in the image contain connection to databases which sometime might get lost and will run forever, after setting timeout on task level by using (execution_timeout)when the tasks reach the timeout , it will be stoped and considered as failed and the whole dag is failed , the problem is the pod will continue to run eventhough the task faild, after 10 minutes the dag execute again and another task will get executed performing the same code and cause duplication

Comment: Apparently there is an ongoing issue with Airflow, [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-6580). You can follow this issue for any updates. Also, can you tell me which version of the Airflow you are using?

Comment: OK so it's a bug in airflow, thanks for informing me, I had to add the timeout inside the code in the docker image to be on the safe side and added a max_active_run also, I'm using  Airflow 1.10.1-composer  (Google Cloud Composer)

Comment: I understand. I am glad you ensured the max_active_run  as well. You are using an older version of the airflow, and the bug is for *1.10.2*. So this maybe be your issue. Currently, Airflow and Composer versions are : **Airflow 1.10.6** and **Composer composer-1.10.5-airflow-1.10.6**. Can you update your environment? Also, would you mind if I post the info I shared with you as an answer in order to further contribute to the community?

Comment: I'll try to discuss that with our DevOps team, and yes I think it's better if you posted this as an answer, thanks!

Comment: I have posted the answer. Please consider accepting and upvoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comment section, I am summarising out discussion as an answer in order to further help the community.

According to the documentation, the parameter ***dagrun_timeout*** specifies how long a DagRun should be up before timing out / failing, so that new DagRuns can be created. In addition, The timeout is only enforced for scheduled DagRuns, and only once the number of ***active DagRuns == max_active_runs***.

As per today,there is an ongoing issue with Airflow  1.10.2,the issue reported description is : *Related to this, when we manually fail a task, the DAG task stops running, but the Pod in the DAG does not get killed and continues running.* This description matches yours. Although, the current version in Google Cloud Platform are ***Airflow 1.10.6*** and ***Composer composer-1.10.5-airflow-1.10.6***. Thus, for this reason, I strongly encourage you to update your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the configuration you have used is at DAG level to timeout and mark DAG as failed. I would recommend  to use TASK level timeout refer [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html?highlight=execution_timeout)

execution_timeout (datetime.timedelta) – max time allowed for the execution of this task instance, if it goes beyond it will raise and fail.

Let me know this is helpful !

Comment: actually this really timeout the task, but weirdly the pod was still running and when the next scheduled run triggered, that caused a problem

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I see is, when the operator is timeout then have fallback option to kill all the specific running pods.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-dingding/stable/operators.html#sending-messages-from-a-task-callback

Answer (score 0):

We are still seeing this issue unfortunately. Another potential workaround could be to specify activeDeadlineSeconds for the pod itself:

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1PodSpec.md#properties