# Not getting 'of' method for TopicName class using com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using GCP PubSub and using the TopicName class. I want to write the below code:

```
TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
```

But I can't get the `'of'`method.

Please can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code ? Because according to the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/api/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.TopicName.html), there is a constructor within the class TopicName(), which *Constructs a new instance of a TopicName class from the component parts of pattern*.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes: I want to publish a message to pubsub queue. For that I created a topicname in GCP and followed the GCP documentation. However, that 'of' method is not coming after 'TopicName' class.

Comment: have you followed this [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654686/set-a-timeout-for-airflow-kubernetespodoperator-task) in order to create the topic.

Comment: No, I was referring this GCP documentation -> https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher

Comment: Did you follow the [quick start](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) for preparing your environment to use the Java API?

Comment: adding libraries-bom in the pom dependency management fixed the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have summarised our discussion as an answer. Please, consider upvoting and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am summarising our discussion as an answer.

You are referring to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#java), which explains how to publish a message in PubSub using Java and you got an error referent to the `TopicName.of(projectId, topicId)`. Since this method is referenced in the documentation, its execution depends on adding the required Java dependencies. In order to do so, you have to follow the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#install) and prepare your environment. Afterwards, you will be able to follow the [Publishing messages to topics](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted more time than Im willing to admit on this same problem, so Im leaving a solution in case anyone else stumbles on the same issue.

In short, my project uses JHipster and the dependency conflict comes from the order in which the POMs are imported:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- THIS DEPENDENCY HAS TO GO BEFORE THE OTHER ONE  -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>26.15.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.jhipster</groupId>
                <artifactId>jhipster-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${jhipster-dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

I can imagine this could happen with other dependencies.