# No method "of" in the TopicName class

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to implement GCP pubsub and am getting an error on the following line:

```
TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
```

My gradle file file includes the following:

```
eimplementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:20.8.0')
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:1.113.5'
```

Which I got from following https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

Any ideas as to why this is an issue? I have looked at this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703520/not-getting-of-method-for-topicname-class-using-com-google-cloud-pubsub-v1) but it does not appear to have the solution.

Comment: Are you using the correct import in your code?

Comment: I am importing from import com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName;

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't other dependencies that can overwrte the current one?

Comment: Not that i can see. (Or non that are obvious)

Answer (score 0):

As specified in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703520/not-getting-of-method-for-topicname-class-using-com-google-cloud-pubsub-v1) we get these kind of errors due to issue in dependencies specified during the setup.

I followed the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) with the below build.gradle file:

```
Dependencies{
implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:20.8.0')
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub'
}
```

And the message is successfully published in Pubsub.

[image]